# Обособление деепричастного оборота-фразеологизма

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, деепричастный-оборот

1. "Коваленко сидел, надувшись, и молчал".
2. "Осмелев, пробирались по саду, садились на снежной поляне перед домом и начинали выть, не переводя духу".

Являются ли "Сидеть надувшись" и "Не переводя духу" фразеологизмами? Если да, то почему они выделены запятыми?
"Если деепричастный оборот представляет собой фразеологизм, то в предложении он не выделяется запятыми".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Осмелев, пробирались по саду, садились на снежной поляне перед домом и начинали выть, не переводя духу.*** - Запятую ставим, так как деепричастный оборот имеет прямое значение и является свободным словосочетанием: выли и при этом не переводили дух. Оборот можно расчленить, изменить форму слова, что невозможно сделать с фразеологизмом. Ср.: ***не переводя ни на секунду дух.***

***Коваленко сидел, надувшись, и молчал.*** - Однородные сказуемые *сидел и молчал*. Глаголы самодостаточны, равноправны, выражают лексическое значение полно. *Герой сидел и молчал* - это и тебовалось сказать автору. *Надувшись* - обособленное обстоятельство образа действия при одном из сказуемых *сидел*.

Сдедует заметить, что чеховское предложение можно оформить и без запятой. Тогда меняется интонация предложения, ***надувшись*** становится частью сказуемого и перетягивает на себя логическое ударение.

Comment: Запятая там никаким боком. Он не просто сидел, а сидел надутым! Именно часть сказуемого.

Comment: Прекрасно Вас понимаю. Я тоже в первую минуту не стала бы выделять, но у Чехова деепричастие выделено. Попробуйте прочитать предложение по-разному, с учётом вариантной пунктуации.

Comment: Ну, мало ли. У Пушкина тоже есть нечто похожее. Это называется авторская пунктуация ("а я так вижу").

*"Ну, прощай, Маша. Василиса Егоровна, уведи же ее поскорее. (Маша кинулась ему на шею, и зарыдала)"...* Видите последнюю запятую? Это пушкинская.

Comment: В нашем примере авторской пунктуации нет. "Надувшись" выделено по правилу обособления обстоятельств, выраженных одиночным деепричастием.

Comment: Пунктуация именно авторская. Прочтите, в каких случаях одиночное деепричастие НЕ обособляется. Ещё похожий пример: "Она идёт по жизни смеясь".

Comment: Отлично знаю, когда не обособляется). И когда обособляется - тоже знаю. Уберите однородное сказуемое "молчал". Знаки поменяются именно так: Коваленко сидел надувшись. Но у нас Коваленко сидит и молчит. Это другая ситуация.

Comment: Вот другое сказуемое на ситуацию вообще не влияет.

Comment: Выражение "сидел и молчал", "сидит и молчит" очень часто употребляется, оно уже предендует на устойчивость, поэтому вкрапление в него обстоятельства в виде одиночного деепричастия запятыми обозначить можно.

Comment: Можно. "Сидел и молчал, надувшись". Никаких возражений.

Answer (score 1):

1) **Коваленко сидЕл, надУвшись, и молчАл** (А.П. Чехов).

**Нет причин сомневаться в правильности обособления деепричастия в классическом произведении.**

НАДУТЬСЯ 3. Разг. Принять важный, надменный вид. Н. от важности, от спеси. 4. Разг. Обидевшись, нахмуриться, сделать недовольное лицо; обидеться. Он надулся и ушёл домой. Н. на товарища.

***Надувшись*** ― **это не фразеологизм**, но переносное значение слова имеет глагол, от которого образовано деепричастие.

Обособления деепричастия "надувшись" зависит от **структуры** предложения и расстановки в нем **логических ударений.**

В авторском варианте ударение падает и на глагол, и на деепричастие, поэтому деепричастие по смыслу выражает добавочное действие. **Подчеркнуто то, что он сидел и молчал.**

Данная структура предложения допускает и второй вариант (без обособления): Коваленко сидел надУвшись и молчАл.

Здесь деепричастие является необособленным обстоятельством образа действия (употреблено в значении наречия). **Подчеркнуто то, что он не просто сидел, а сидел с недовольным лицом.**

В Нацкорпусе оба варианта встречаются одинаково часто: 
 http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E0%E4%F3%E2%F8%E8%F1%FC&p=7

2) **Осмелев, пробирались по саду, садились на снежной поляне перед домом и начинали вЫть, не переводя дУху.**

**Не переводя духа** ― фразеологический оборот, в данном случае со значением "непрерывно".

Обособление также зависит от структуры предложения, например:  *Не переводя духа я поплыл обратно. Я, не переводя духа,  поплыл обратно.*

Надо сказать, что в большинстве случаев оборот удобно обособить:

Бедный щеголь, **не переводя духу**, осушил весь кубок и отдал его маршалу. [А. С. Пушкин. Арап Петра Великого (1828)]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%E5+%EF%E5%F0%E5%E2%EE%E4%FF+%E4%F3%F5%F3

Comment: Это ошибка, спасибо, исправлено.

Comment: Итак, по-вашему, *сидЕл, надУлся и молчАл*. Замечательно. )

Comment: Нет, это не совсем так, как Вы сказали.  Обособленный член не входит в основное сообщение, он произносится со вставочной интонацией и обозначает дополнительную информацию. В данном случае  (при такой структуре) у автора был выбор: обозначить тесную связь  деепричастия со сказуемым (это Ваш вариант) или обособить его, отнеся интонационно и по смыслу на второй план речи. Практически эти варианты  (для этого предложения) одинаково возможны.

Comment: Обособить – это "сидел и молчал, надувшись". Авторский же вариант с точки зрения современной грамматики – ошибка. Как там было во времена Чехова, не знаю.

Comment: Ну вот похожий пример из Нацкорпуса: "На канапе в той же комнате сидела, надувшись, у стола госпожа Каро и занималась каким-то вязаньем". Здесь деепричастие по смыслу  - такое же дополнительное замечание, попутное уточнение состояния персонажа.

Comment: "Удобно обособить" — такое объяснение ничего не объясняет.

Comment: Удобно обособить - это краткое (обобщенное) объяснение. Если говорить подробно, то это означает, что, к примеру,  оборот "не переводя духу" НЕ ВПИСЫВАЕТСЯ в структуру основного предложения. При отсутствии обособления нужно в одну фразу прочитать "Бедный щеголь не переводя духу осушил весь кубок", и здесь нужны хотя бы произносительные паузы. И где мы будем их располагать, на каком слове делать основное тоническое ударение?Поэтому здесь весь оборот удобно отнести на второй план, исключив из основного предложения и прочитать как вставку.

Answer (score 0):

Сидеть надувшись – не фразеологизм. Но, поскольку деепричастие тесно связано со сказуемым, обособлять его не следует.

Второй пример потруднее. Думаю, возможны оба варианта. Я бы не обособлял. Тоже тесная связь со сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

1. По-моему, нет такого фразеологизма "сидеть надувшись". Также нельзя сказать, что "надувшись" — это образ действия для глагола "сидеть".  Не вижу тесной связи со сказуемым (он сидел и молчал, а при этом был надут).  Есть все основания выделить деепричастие "надувшись" запятыми.
2. Фразеологизмам "не переводя духу" есть, но употребляется в переносном смысле (без остановки). Возможно, здесь прямой смысл (не делая вдохов), поэтому стоит запятая. Я бы не отвергал и вариант без запятой (со смыслом "без остановки").